# Tex4ht, LaTeX to Docbook: Quote-Environment not transformed to <blockquote>

Tags: tex4ht, xml

I've been using Tex4ht to create a Word-File from LaTeX via ODT (oolatex). I've been wondering if the conversion process can be easier if we generate a Docbook XML from LaTeX. This could be the transformed to DOCX with pandoc.

Now, if I have a basic file like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 Some Text

 \begin{quote}
 A quotation.
 \end{quote}

 Some more text.

 \end{document}
```

The relevant part in the resulting Docbook XML looks like this:

```
 --><para>Some Text</para><!--l. 7
 --><para>A quotation.</para><!--l. 10
 --><para>Some more text.</para>
```

Why is the quote-environment not transformed into a blockquote element? Is this a bug? How can we get the supposed behavior?

Comment: the `Docbook` support is nowhere as complete as `HTML` or `ODT` support in `tex4ht`. so configuration for `quote` is just missing. why do you think it will be easier to use `Docbook` instead of  `ODT`?

Comment: Ok. I supposed that a rather basic construct like `quote` would be covered.

Comment: Concerning `Docbook` being easier to use than `ODT`: First, I have the impression that `Docbook` is cleaner, better to read and better to parse than `ODT`, probably since it is a intended for composing documents, whereas `ODT` is a file format.  Also, I find the documentation more accessible.

Comment: I've added the configuration for `quote` to `tex4ht` sources, so this change should be included in TeX distributions soon, hopefully. Nobody is working on the Docbook support systematically, so I am sure many more things are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration for `quote` environment is missing in `tex4ht` support for Docbook. You can try the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ConfigureEnv{quote}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<blockquote>}}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</blockquote>}\par\ShowPar}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It will insert `<blockqoute>` element around the `quote` environment contents. The `\IgnorePar`, `\EndP` and `\ShowPar` will fix possible issues with paragraphs.

This is the result:

```xml
<article
 xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="5.0"><title
></title> 

<!--l. 3
--><para>Some Text</para><blockquote
>
     <!--l. 6
--><para>A quotation.</para></blockquote>
<!--l. 9
--><para>Some more text.</para></article>
```

Comment: Great. But why is the opening <blockquote> a line before the quotation itself (and the closing </blockquote>)?